# Paypal 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, paypal

I am working with paypal and I am using the following code :

```
$(".btn-small").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
         url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/paypal/buy'); ?>",
         type:"POST",  
         crossDomain :"true",
         success:function()
         {
            alert("Success : ");
         },
         error:function()
         {
            alert("Failed : ");
         }
        });

    });
```

But I am getting the error as
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/xxxxxxxxxxx. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have gone through many posts I understood the two solutions

1. use JSONP
2. CORS.

I have used JSONP like this:

```
$(".btn-small").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
             url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/paypal/buy'); ?>",
             type:"POST",  
             crossDomain :"true",
             dataType:"jsonp",
             success:function()
             {
                alert("Success : ");
             },
             error:function()
             {
                alert("Failed : ");
             }
            });

        });
```

but then I get the following error :

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, I think this is because I am getting response as html.

I have used CORS like this :

```
$(".btn-small").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
             url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/paypal/buy'); ?>",
             type:"POST",  
            headers: {

             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
             'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
             'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description'
            },

             crossDomain :"true",
             success:function()
             {
                alert("Success : ");
             },
             error:function()
             {
                alert("Failed : ");
             }
            });

        });
```

but I am getting the same error as :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/xxxxxxxxxxx. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

ANY HELP PLEASE.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Comment: Are you sure the PayPal API your using is not designed to be POSTed to from the *server* as opposed to the *client* ? If you *are* sure the URL is likely wrong as it would have to contain the appropriate header and clearly does not.

Comment: Extremly sorrly Alex I did not understood what you want to say. if you are asking about JSONP then I have also worked with GET as the type in ajax , but I am still facing the same error.

Comment: What is the exact PayPal API call you are attempting?

Comment: I am using paypal SDK.....on my button click I want to go to the sandbox url for payment.

Comment: The controller which I am using already contains action as buy which will take me to paypal login page.
I am able to go to that url normally but when I use it with ajax I am facing such problems.

Comment: This is the first time I am working with paypal or such party and being very honest I am not a good programmer.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and co are **response headers** not request headers. It would be pretty stupid if your JavaScript could grant itself permission to access other people's data.

Comment: It *looks* (and I have no experience with this) like you aren't using the PayPal JS API at all: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/

Comment: You use `$.ajax` to post to **your** web server. Your web server takes what you posted and sends it to **paypal** (via `curl`). Your web server waits for the response. PayPal responds, your web server returns info to your web application. If you try directly posting to paypal.com, you will get the error you got. Browsers prohibit sending stuff from domain `a` to domain `b` unless configured otherwise. Seeing you cant configure paypal's domain or server, the option you're left with is what I explained.

Comment: Thank you very much Quentin and Mjh....It helped me a lot to understand the problem..thank you very much..I will try to work out with the solutions both of you have provided.